# Cron Job for Windows error: Could not find a file

Tags: c#, cron, cron-task

Hi When I run my **C# Console Application** manually just opening it, my internal code in which opens the file **\server\folder\database.mdb**  works fine, but when I run the same C# Console Application openning through a Cron job for Windows It returns the error:

> Could not find the file \server\folder\database.mdb

How is it possible, it is inside my c# code, what does Cronjob that gives me this error?

Is there any #path configuration or environment variable or even a default folder that cron job uses, do I need to change something to work with Cron jobs?

Comment: I'm curious, is there any reason you are not using the Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: @SteveWellens I use it because I like the config file that I can schedule easily many process to run in certain times...

Answer (score 0):

The user under which task scheduler is running may not have permissions  to that folder